# If a column has a value add via update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column `transfer_quantity` which has an initial value of 0. When I input some number on my input field

```
<input type="number" name="qtyBuy">
```

I want to update my `transfer_quantity` to my `qtyBuy` value.

Here is my initial code:

```
UPDATE stock_transfer SET stocks_transferred = $qtyBuy WHERE transfer_product_id = 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stocks_transferred = stocks_transferred + $qtyBuy;
```

Here's an example:

```
|stocks_transferred|
|       0          |
```

When I input 10, this should be the result:

```
|stocks_transferred|
|       10          |
```

and if I input 25, it should add with the 10 in the

```
|stocks_transferred|
|       35         |
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `UPDATE stock_transfer SET stocks_transferred = $qtyBuy WHERE transfer_product_id = 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stocks_transferred = stocks_transferred + $qtyBuy;` This query doesn't work?

Comment: Why you don't simply query stocks_transferred and add your input number to it and then update the value in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE stock_transfer SET stocks_transferred = stocks_transferred + $qtyBuy WHERE transfer_product_id = 1
```